# C/c++ related questions . Logic making queries

Tags: visual-c++

User enters a sentence and a word which he wants to search both. Now we need to find whether word is there or not . without using string functions

Comment: The title of your post mentions "questions", but the body doesn't contain any.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop your own function if you dont want to to use string functions,
for example the function you want would be similar to this one:

```
bool find( char * str, char * word )
{
    int i,j,k,l;
    i = strlen( str );
    k = strlen( word ); 
    l = 0;
    while ( i >= k )
    {
        j = 0;
        while ( *(str+j+l) == *(word+j) )
        {
            j++;
        }
        i--; l++;
        if ( j >= k )
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

In above example 'str' would be the string in which you want to search and 'word' would the string you want to search.